# PHP MongoDB Collection Export to CSV issue

Tags: php-mongodb

I have collection with following data set

```
MongoDB Enterprise > db.UCODEPatter.find()
{ "_id" : { "UCODE" : NumberLong("233220524641368") }, "value" : 117 }
{ "_id" : { "UCODE" : NumberLong("233222325602424") }, "value" : 71 }
{ "_id" : { "UCODE" : NumberLong("233222325601932") }, "value" : 69 }
{ "_id" : { "UCODE" : NumberLong("233222325601947") }, "value" : 59 }
{ "_id" : { "UCODE" : NumberLong("233222325602414") }, "value" : 58 }
{ "_id" : { "UCODE" : NumberLong("233222325602419") }, "value" : 49 }
{ "_id" : { "UCODE" : NumberLong("233222325602418") }, "value" : 48 }
{ "_id" : { "UCODE" : NumberLong("233220535710165") }, "value" : 47 }
{ "_id" : { "UCODE" : NumberLong("233222325602405") }, "value" : 46 }
{ "_id" : { "UCODE" : NumberLong("233222325602420") }, "value" : 45 }
{ "_id" : { "UCODE" : NumberLong("233220537026120") }, "value" : 45 }
{ "_id" : { "UCODE" : NumberLong("233222686003297") }, "value" : 44 }
{ "_id" : { "UCODE" : NumberLong("233222325602417") }, "value" : 44 }
```

i am try to export above data as CSV file using PHP , here my php code

```
<?php

header('Content-Type: application/csv');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=example.csv');
header('Pragma: no-cache');

$database   = "LogData";
$colName    = "UCODEPatter";
$connection = new MongoClient();
$collection = $connection->$colName->$database;

$cursor     = $collection->find();
foreach($cursor as $cur)
   echo '"'.$cur["UCODE"].'","'.$cur['value']."\"\n";       

?>
```

when i used above code , i created csv file without data, please kindly help me to sort this

Answer (score 0):

I think, you messed up with methods here:

```
$collection = $connection->$colName->$database;
```

There should be this:

```
$collection = $connection->selectDB($database)->selectCollection($colName);
```

And you didn't show that your collection exists in db named "LogData", so you should check this.